# Quantmod: Error loading symbols from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, r, quantmod

I am trying to fetch symbols from a MySQL db using getSymbols, however the following code

```
library(blotter)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL) 
setDefaults(getSymbols.MySQL,user="****", password="****", dbname="quantmoddb")
currency("USD")
stock("myspy",currency="USD",multiplier=1)
getSymbols("myspy",src="MySQL")
```

throws

```
  Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"character"’
```

I am pretty sure the db is set up correctly as the following code runs fine and returns the dataset as expected.

```
 con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),user="****",password="****", dbname="quantmoddb",
                       host="localhost", port=3306) 
 db.Symbols <- DBI::dbListTables(con)
 query <- paste("SELECT * from myspy ORDER BY date")
 rs <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, query)
 fr <- DBI::fetch(rs, n=-1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try making [this suggested edit](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/62#issuecomment-87692704) to the quantmod source, and then rebuild and install? Hopefully that will resolve the issue.

Comment: I will certainly give it a try. But I cannot promise anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"character"` method for `dbConnect` [was removed](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/commit/051eeddcf6e8e0ccac9ae6bef42343241ff2b264#diff-30bde6a0d7563b50611c11cb8b94575cL12) in the 0.10 release of RMySQL. I'm not sure whether or not this was intentional. It was not mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: Ok, thx for the confirmation. Do you plan to fix this in the next release? Btw. why is the getSymbols.Bloomberg function commented out? Anyway, great package.

Comment: @chuchikaeschtli: I opened [an issue on RMySQL](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/62) to see if it was intentional. I'll attempt to fix if it was, but I could use help because I don't use this functionality, nor do I have a MySQL DB to test against. I don't think `getSymbols.Bloomberg` was ever implemented.

Comment: I'd like to help if possible but first I have to get a bit more familiar with the R ecosystem (how to build packages etc.). there is definitely a getSymbols.Bloomberg method (in getSymbols.R starting at line 119, although everything is commented out). is the code in your github repository the actual development version?

Comment: I know the function is there. I have no idea whether or not it works, and I don't have a Bloomberg terminal to test it. Yes, the code in my GitHub repo is the development version (I'm the maintainer).