# quantmod R getsymbols.MySQL modification

Tags: mysql, r, quantmod

I have already studied the case
[Quantmod: Error loading symbols from MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333330/quantmod-error-loading-symbols-from-mysql-db)
and already try to fix the getSymbols.MySQL function in R

However, I found that my database just contain
date, open, high, low, close, volume (without the close.adj column).
So, if I want to further modify the getSymbols.MySQL function, what can I do?

I have tried to use 'fix(getSymbols.MySQL)' to fix the function. However, it returns

*Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("H0001.Open", "H0001.High", "H0001.Low",  : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent*

when I connect to my database.

```
function (Symbols, env, return.class = "xts", db.fields = c("date", 
"o", "h", "l", "c", "v", "a"), field.names = NULL, user = NULL, 
password = NULL, dbname = NULL, host = "localhost", port = 3306, 
...) 
{
importDefaults("getSymbols.MySQL")
this.env <- environment()
for (var in names(list(...))) {
    assign(var, list(...)[[var]], this.env)
}
if (!hasArg(verbose)) 
    verbose <- FALSE
if (!hasArg(auto.assign)) 
    auto.assign <- TRUE
if (!requireNamespace("DBI", quietly = TRUE)) 
    stop("package:", dQuote("DBI"), "cannot be loaded.")
if (!requireNamespace("RMySQL", quietly = TRUE)) 
    stop("package:", dQuote("RMySQL"), "cannot be loaded.")
if (is.null(user) || is.null(password) || is.null(dbname)) {
    stop(paste("At least one connection argument (", sQuote("user"), 
        sQuote("password"), sQuote("dbname"), ") is not set"))
}
con <- DBI::dbConnect("MySQL", user = user, password = password, 
    dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port)
db.Symbols <- DBI::dbListTables(con)
if (length(Symbols) != sum(Symbols %in% db.Symbols)) {
    missing.db.symbol <- Symbols[!Symbols %in% db.Symbols]
    warning(paste("could not load symbol(s): ", paste(missing.db.symbol, 
        collapse = ", ")))
    Symbols <- Symbols[Symbols %in% db.Symbols]
}
for (i in 1:length(Symbols)) {
    if (verbose) {
        cat(paste("Loading ", Symbols[[i]], paste(rep(".", 
            10 - nchar(Symbols[[i]])), collapse = ""), sep = ""))
    }
    query <- paste("SELECT ", paste(db.fields, collapse = ","), 
        " FROM ", Symbols[[i]], " ORDER BY date")
    rs <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, query)
    fr <- DBI::fetch(rs, n = -1)
    fr <- xts(as.matrix(fr[, -1]), order.by = as.Date(fr[, 
        1], origin = "1970-01-01"), src = dbname, updated = Sys.time())
    colnames(fr) <- paste(Symbols[[i]], c("Open", "High", 
        "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted"), sep = ".")
    fr <- convert.time.series(fr = fr, return.class = return.class)
    if (auto.assign) 
        assign(Symbols[[i]], fr, env)
    if (verbose) 
        cat("done\n")
}
DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
if (auto.assign) 
    return(Symbols)
return(fr)
}
```

I think the problem is the function was designed to read 7 column of data rather than 6 column of data. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Why doesn't setting `db.fields` work? And keep the *Note* section in `?getSymbols.MySQL` in mind.

Comment: getSymbols.MySQL("H0001", env, return.class = 'xts', db.fields = c("date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"), user = 'xxxx', password = 'xxxx', host='xxxx', dbname = 'xxxx'), it does not work.

Comment: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("H0001.Open", "H0001.High", "H0001.Low",  :   length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent 
`colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("H0001.Open", "H0001.High", "H0001.Low", "H0001.Close", "H0001.Volume", "H0001.Adjusted")) ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a patch that should allow you to do what you want. I'm unable to test because I don't have a MySQL installation to test against.  Please let me know whether or not it works.

```
diff --git a/R/getSymbols.R b/R/getSymbols.R
index 0a2e814..7a9be66 100644
--- a/R/getSymbols.R
+++ b/R/getSymbols.R
@@ -634,9 +634,9 @@ function(Symbols,env,return.class='xts',
             fr <- xts(as.matrix(fr[,-1]),
                       order.by=as.Date(fr[,1],origin='1970-01-01'),
                       src=dbname,updated=Sys.time())
-            colnames(fr) <- paste(Symbols[[i]],
-                                  c('Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adjusted'),
-                                  sep='.')
+            if(is.null(field.names))
+              field.names <- c('Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adjusted')
+            colnames(fr) <- paste(Symbols[[i]], field.names, sep='.')
             fr <- convert.time.series(fr=fr,return.class=return.class)
             if(auto.assign)
               assign(Symbols[[i]],fr,env)
```

Then your function call should be:

```
getSymbols.MySQL("H0001", env, return.class = 'xts',
  db.fields = c("date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"),
  field.names = c("date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"),
  user = 'xxxx', password = 'xxxx', host='xxxx', dbname = 'xxxx')
```

Comment: How can I share the MySQL to you? by e mail? Today, I got this error...  **Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"character"’**

Comment: @tw123789: you also need [this patch](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/compare/RMySQL_45), which I also cannot test. Please do not try to email me your database...

Comment: I forgot to put the () after RMySQL:MySQL. But the problem still exists  **Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("H0001.date", "H0001.open", "H0001.high",: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent 
5 `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("H0001.date", "H0001.open", "H0001.high", "H0001.low", "H0001.close", "H0001.volume")) 
4 `dimnames<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = dn) 
3 `dimnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = dn) 
2 `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("H0001.date", "H0001.open", "H0001.high", "H0001.low", "H0001.close", "H0001.volume")) at C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGcphw0\file1940242c330#46**

Comment: oh, I think that is because I delete a row in MySQL so that the amendment cannot function well. I have edited MySQL and eventually pop up **Error in charToDate(x) :   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format**

Comment: MySQL should run nothing error because it has "date" format for date and it shows "2015-05-21" in the column of "date". So, i think this is the problem due to R extracting the data from MySQL, any idea?

Comment: R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-4 TTR_0.22-0     xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-12     RMySQL_0.10.3  DBI_0.3.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
...

Comment: I got this eventually pop up  `function (x) 
{
    xx <- x[1L]
    if (is.na(xx)) {
        j <- 1L
        while (is.na(xx) && (j <- j + 1L) <= length(x)) xx <- x[j]
        if (is.na(xx)) 
            f <- "%Y-%m-%d"
    }
    if (is.na(xx) || !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT")) || 
        !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d", tz = "GMT"))) 
        return(strptime(x, f))
    stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
}`

Comment: I can make the query from MySQL `res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT date, close FROM H0001 WHERE date > '2015-05-18'")` and `dbFetch(res)` but cannot use getSymbols.MySQL...

Comment: I think the problem is in the string 0000-00-00 in MySQL. if I delete it, it showed **Error in colnames <- (*tmp*, value = c("A0001.date", A0001,open, A0001.high: length of 'dimnames' not equal to array extent** if I left it exist in MySQL, the function pop up **Error in charToDate(x) :   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format**

Comment: @tw123789: yes, "0000-00-00" would be a problem because it's not a valid date.

Comment: any idea to sort it out.? If i delete than string., it seems r can't download the data...

Comment: I prefer delete the 0000-00-00, `getSymbols.MySQL("H0001", env, return.class = 'xts', db.fields = c('date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'), field.names = c('date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'), user = 'xxx', password = 'xxx', host='xxx', dbname = 'xxx')` the **Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("H0001.date", "H0001.open", "H0001.high",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
Called from: `dimnames<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = dn)** still exists

Comment: I created my database first and containing the columns with names (Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adjusted) to eliminate the error due to column missing. I ran the original getSymbols.MySQL (with only change "MySQL" to RMySQL::MySQL() `getSymbols.MySQL("H0002", env, return.class = 'xts', db.fields = c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted"), field.names = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted"), user = 'xxx', password = 'xxx', host='xxx', dbname = 'xxx')` which returned **Error: could not find function "convert.time.series"**

Comment: I should think outside the box. if getSymbol,MySQL is not available, I should use other method to create xts object by MySQL query. I am trying to solve this problem in other way. Thanks